# how to change user control to user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I have 2 user controls. 1 - login uc. 2 - register uc.

Login user control:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Views.LoginView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Width="350"
        Height="500">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Height="280" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Aqua"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF34268A" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle Width="280" Height="240" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,80" RadiusY="10" RadiusX="10" Fill="White">
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15" Direction="0" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="1" Color="#FFBBBBBB"/>
            </Rectangle.Effect>
        </Rectangle>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="35,80" Height="240">
            <Label Content="Вход" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="18"/>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15">
                <TextBox x:Name="Username" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Логин" Margin="0,10"  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" FontFamily="Champagne &amp; Limousines" FontSize="18"/>
                <PasswordBox x:Name="Password" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint= "Пароль" Margin="0,10" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintPasswordBox}" FontFamily="Champagne &amp; Limousines" FontSize="18"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Login" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,65" Content="Войти"/>
        <Button x:Name="Register" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5" Content="Register?" Background="{x:Null}"/>
        <Image Source="/Project;component/Assets/smartphone.png" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Register user control:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Views.RegisterView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Width="350"
             Height="800">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Height="280" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Aqua"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF34268A" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle Width="280" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,80" RadiusY="10" RadiusX="10" Fill="White">
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15" Direction="0" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="1" Color="#FFBBBBBB"/>
            </Rectangle.Effect>
        </Rectangle>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="35,80" Height="500">
            <Label Content="Регистрация" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="18"/>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15">
                <TextBox x:Name="Email" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Email" Margin="0,10"  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" FontFamily="Champagne &amp; Limousines" FontSize="18"/>
                <PasswordBox x:Name="Password" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint= "Пароль" Margin="0,10" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintPasswordBox}" FontFamily="Champagne &amp; Limousines" FontSize="18"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Username" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Имя" Margin="0,10"  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" FontFamily="Champagne &amp; Limousines" FontSize="18"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Surname" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Фамилия" Margin="0,10"  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" FontFamily="Champagne &amp; Limousines" FontSize="18"/>
                <DatePicker x:Name="BirthdayDate" Margin="0,10" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Выберите дату рождения" FontFamily="Champagne &amp; Limousines" FontSize="18"/>
                <Button x:Name="SelectPhoto" Content="Выбор фото"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Register" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,65" Content="Зарегистрироваться"/>
        <Image Source="/Project;component/Assets/smartphone.png" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My bootstrapper:

```cs
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        private SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();
        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();

            ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<PasswordBox>(
            PasswordBoxHelper.BoundPasswordProperty,
            "Password",
            "PasswordChanged");
        }
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
            _container.Singleton<LoginViewModel>();
            _container.Singleton<RegisterViewModel>();
            _container.Singleton<HomeViewModel>();
            _container.Singleton<ShellViewModel>();
        }
        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
        }
        protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
        {
            return _container.GetInstance(service, key);
        }
        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
        {
            return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
        }
        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            _container.BuildUp(instance);
        }
    }
```

And there is a window in which I want to change these user control:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Project.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SocialNetwork.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Width="350"
        Height="500">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ShellViewModel:

```cs
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
    {
        private LoginViewModel _loginViewModel;
        private RegisterViewModel _registerViewModel;
        public ShellViewModel(LoginViewModel loginViewModel, RegisterViewModel registerViewModel)
        {
            DisplayName = "Войти";
            _loginViewModel = loginViewModel;
            _registerViewModel = registerViewModel;
            ActivateItemAsync(_loginViewModel);
        }
    }
```

How do I click on the Register button in login user control, change it to register user control?, and when you click on the Register button in register user control, change back register to login?

I did it like this:

### Update

```cs
public Task HandleAsync(ChangeViewMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (message.ViewModelType.Name.Equals("LoginViewModel"))
            {
               DisplayName = "Регистрация";
               
               NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DisplayName);
               return ActivateItemAsync(_registerViewModel);
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayName = "Вход";
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DisplayName);
                return ActivateItemAsync(_loginViewModel);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use the [event aggreator](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator) to send an event or a message from the view model to the shell.

The idea is that the `ShellViewModel` handles the event by activating the view:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>, IHandle<ChangeViewMessage>
{
    public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        ...
    }

    public void Handle(ChangeViewMessage message)
    {
        // call ActivateItemAsync based on type here...
    }
    
    ...
}

public class ChangeViewMessage
{
    public readonly Type ViewModelType;

    public ChangeViewMessage(Type viewModelType)
    {
        ViewModelType = viewModelType;
    }
}
```

And the `LoginViewModel` and `RegisterViewModel` classes publish events, e.g.:

```
eventAggregator.Publish(new ChangeViewType(this.GetType()));
```

Comment: should my usercontrol inherit from ChangeViewMessage? I didn't understand it a bit, but the approach is definitely elegant.

Comment: I added the code, but writes in the view that I could not find such a view. Program.ChangeViewMessage.View not found.

Comment: No, `ChangeViewMessage` is a custom class that you need to create yourself. You can copy my sample class in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did, but I don't know how much is correct)